# Saving details before master?

Tags: c#, sql, logic

I have a table called Bank which stores bank information such as name, account, subsidiaries/branches. For entering subsidiaries/branches I am using the same table and including fields ParentId, IsSubsidiary, IsBranch which is self-referencing. Table structure as below:

```
Field            Type
---------------------------
BankId           int (PK)
Name             nvarchar(100)
AccountNo        nvarchar(50)
ParentId         int (self-referencing key)
IsSubsidiary     bit
IsBranch         bit
```

So I am making a C# application to capture this information and I want to reuse the same form to capture subsidiary data.
For example:

> Enter parent: Bank A
>       Enter Bank A's branches: Bank B and Bank C

The issue is while entering Bank A's data, the user wants to enter it's branches (Bank B and Bank C) details, so how can I the ParentId be generated when user as not yet saved Bank A data?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this, one of which would be to use a uniqueidentifier data type for the BankId field (I assume you are using SQL Server). This way you *could* generate a Guid in C# using Guid.NewGuid() and use that for the ID, before you save any records.

That said, a better solution would probably be to cache any changes and save things in the proper order. Save the parent first, and then the children.

Comment: Changing the data type to uniqueidentifier is not an option for me as this table is already linked with so many other tables. Can you provide some more information on how I can achieve this using cache?

Comment: All I meant with "cache" was to save the data in variables in your application for later, so that once you save the parent, you can save the children later. I don't think there's really any other options if you are required to use a SQL Server int identity column for the ID. You could try and query the database to guess what the next ID will be, and use that, but I would consider that very bad practice and it wouldn't work anyways unless you disable any foreign keys (also bad practice).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you insert records to DB. One solution is use "output". when you insert BankA, you can get the id with output of inserted.BankID

Comment: The interface is such that it saves all information related to Bank A then saves Bank A.

Comment: To me it's really a bad approach to save BankA last. If this is the case, (I assume the BankID is allocated by DB), you will need to update the ParentID as the final step.